# Bottom of compose Popup not fit screen

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

I found this strange problem when use `ModalBottomSheet`, and it seems the problem of `Popup` component.

landscape mode screenshot

[image: 1]

portrait mode screenshot

[image: 2]

Here is simple example code.

```
MaterialTheme {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White),
    ) {
        Text(
            "TopEnd",
            fontSize = 32.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd)
        )
        Text(
            "BottomEnd",
            fontSize = 32.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
        )
    }

    Popup {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(
                    Color.Blue.copy(
                        alpha = 0.2F
                    )
                ),
        ) {
            Text(
                "PopupTopStart",
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopStart)
            )
            Text(
                "PopupBottomStart",
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ModalBottomSheet` is buggy for some time now, i've stopped using it until some fixes come.

Maybe your problem is related to theses unwanted behaviors.

See the issues: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268380384

Hope it helps.